# Trouble getting rid of duplicate links

Tags: python, web-scraping, duplicates, web-crawler

Tried with many different links but every time I get the same result which is: the first link always ends up in last again.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
Unique=[]
url="https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA"
def DupRemoval(Address):
    MainLink="https://www.yellowpages.com"
    response = requests.get(Address)
    Unique.append(Address)
    tree=html.fromstring(response.text)
    Pagination_link=tree.xpath("//div[@class='pagination']//a/@href")
    for Nextpage in Pagination_link:
        Blink=MainLink+Nextpage
        if Blink not in Unique:
            print(Blink)

DupRemoval(url)
```

Produced Links:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using a set instead of a list which allows duplicates?

Comment: Yep sir  cricket_007, tried that in the first place but no luck.

Comment: Then something in the URL string must be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate link is the "Next" link button which is the last one in the pagination block. Moreover, if you advance further to next pages, you'll also get the "Previous" link there as well.

A quick way to filter it out would be to get all `a` elements without the `class` attribute:

```
//div[@class='pagination']//a[not(@class)]/@href
```

Comment: Thanks sir alecxe, for your effective solution as always. You are the wizard in coding. Btw, do you think that the code i pasted above was allright other than the xpath? Thanks again.

Comment: @SMth80 thanks! There are things I would improve there - consider posting it to the [Code Review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - great way to get feedback for a working code.

Comment: One thing to know sir, about xpath expression. The other day you taught me about writing xpath when class elements contain space between them. This time i tried like this but unfortunately it throws error. I don't understand if any mistakes i'm making here. If you take a look on this, i'll be very happy. Thanks again sir alecxe. "//div[@class='pagination']//a[contains(concat(' ', @cla‌​ss, ' '), ' next ')]/@hr‌​ef"

Comment: @SMth80 sure, your expression actually looks good - it matches the `href` value of the "next" link. Note that, when I copy-pasted it, there were some non-printed symbols there - try this one instead: `//div[@class='pagination']//a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' next ')]/@href`. Thanks.

Comment: Your one always rocks sir. But I'm still confused, where did i do wrong in my xpath. In fact, i cant still don't find the difference. Yet, your one is working and my one is throwing errors. You will be surprised to see that again. Btw, thanks for your time sir.                                              
 Your One-//div[@class='pagination']//a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' next ')]/@href
My One-//div[@class='pagination']//a[contains(concat(' ', @cla‌​ss, ' '), ' next ')]/@hr‌​ef

Comment: @SMth80 that's exactly the point - you don't see the difference visually, but there are unprinted characters after the `a` inside `@class` and after `r` inside `@href`. I see that in the chrome console when I paste your expression into the `$x()` function to test the XPath. Hope that helps.

Comment: Long live sir alecxe!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Much obliged. Now, I'll be able to think otherwise.